# zendesk authentication in zapier code

Tags: node.js, zapier, zendesk-api

I am building a zap in zapier where I need authenticate zendesk manually in code. Only vanilla nodejs codes are supported there and the fetch method. I was following the zendesk documentation here https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction#security-and-authentication and its a curl command

```
curl -u jdoe@example.com/token:6wiIBWbGkBMo1mRDMuVwkw1EPsNkeUj95PIz2akv https://obscura.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json
```

So how can I write this in zapier code?

Answer (score 0):

In your pre proll or pre write function you should be encoding your authentication in your header.

to transform your user/pwd in base64:
https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/built-functions-tools/#base-64-encoding

```
var token = btoa(jdoe@example.com/token:6wiIBWbGkBMo1mRDMuVwkw1EPsNkeUj95PIz2akv);

bundle.request.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + token ;
```